# check multiple NAS directories for folder PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a list of NAS folders that I have to regularly query for folder existence. Each query is unique but might live under any of 40+ directories.  The directories are fixed and I am only looking for a true or null (to all directories) response. I need to have a user input box and an output to either a txt file or a popup dialogue with the validated UNC path.
PowerShell has the helpful Test-Path, Read-Host and Get-Content functions that I think I'll be using but am open to other ideas.  Here's my beginning thoughts any help would be appreciated.

My variables

```
    $Folderquery = Read-Host 'Enter remote folder name'
    $potentialpaths = Get-Content \\nas\listofpaths.txt
```

My command that works when I store the single variable $Folderquery and run it against each possible UNC path

```
    Test-Path \\NAS1\Folder1\$Folderquery
```

I am thinking that I need to have all of my possible UNC test paths in the listofpaths.txt file as each NAS has several hundred primary folders and I only want to scan within a small subsection of those.

```
    Foreach ($potentialpaths in (Get-Content \\NAS\listofpaths.txt))
    {
    If (-not (Test-Path $Folderquery)) {
    Write-Output "The Folder $Folderquery does not exist"
    }
    else {
    Write-Output "The Folder $Folderquery has been found on $listofpaths
    }
```

So, how do I put it all together?

Revised code:

```
$Folderquery = Read-Host 'Enter remote folder name'
$i = 0
foreach ($potentialpath in (Get-Content \\NAS\listofpaths.txt))
{
  If (Test-Path "$potentialpath\$Folderquery") 
  {
    $i++
  }
}
If ($i -eq 1)
{
  Write-Output "The Folder $Folderquery exists on $potentialpath\$Folderquery" | Out-File "\\NAS\pathlogfile.log" -Encoding ASCII -Append
} 
Elseif ($i -eq 0)
{
  Write-Output "The Folder $Folderquery does not exist" | Out-File "\\NAS\pathlogfile.log" -Encoding ASCII -Append
}
```

Where should I break? How do I group those statements to make them effective?

Comment: {
    Else
     } 
    If ($i -eq 1)
    {
      Write-Output "The Folder $Folderquery exists on $potentialpath\$Folderquery" | Out-File "\\NAS\pathlogfile.log" -Encoding ASCII -Append
      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're printing the folder exists message outside of the loop, at which point $potentialpaths (name ought to be singular rather than plural) has the value it was given on the last iteration of the loop. Print that message from inside the if(Test-Path) block and break/return/exit depending on the larger context, and given that there is either zero or one instance of $Folderquery, or at least you're only interested in the first one.

Comment: I have posted revised code above but with my limited understanding am not sure where to put the break so that it recurses properly or runs at all.

Comment: The strategy of counting matches would seem to be too much work.  You can stop as soon as you find the first match.  This would be a break statement immediately after the $i++ statement.

Comment: Reading about breaks now. Looks like there are different ones... I just inserted "Break" on the line after i++ (line 8) and that seems to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're very close to your answer already, is this what you are looking for?

```
$Folderquery = Read-Host 'Enter remote folder name'
$i = 0

Foreach ($potentialpath in (Get-Content \\NAS\listofpaths.txt))
{
  If (Test-Path "$potentialpath\$Folderquery") 
  {
    $i++
  }
}

If ($i -eq 0)
{
  Write-Output "The Folder $Folderquery does not exist" | Out-File "C:\logfile.log" -Encoding ASCII -Append
}
```

Comment: I tried your script but I Get a MissingEndCurlyBrace c:\testpath.ps1:10 char:2

Looking at that syntax I think I need to specify a log or modal output? Also, I was trying to only receive a not present if the file did not exist on any of the locations and to have a pop up input box ala VBS userinput box. So, I think I need a bit more that where we are now.

Comment: Fixed the missing bracket and added a log output.

Comment: Works wonderfully, with the exception that I may have muddied the waters. The script only replies if there is not the folder on the the potential paths which is what I think I said... in the previous response.
What I was trying to accomplish was a positive response if a file existed and a negative if it did not exist on any of the paths. The outputs I need are:
    "The Folder $Folderquery does not exist"
and
    "The Folder $Folderquery exists on $potentialpath"
Sorry, I lost sight of the forest in my response.

Comment: Got it figured out, let me know if there is a more elegant way to do this. Will post code above

Comment: OK, just kidding... that will tell me that the folder does exist accurately. However, it does not tell me the proper path. It is defaulting to the last folder in the list of paths